# Setting options to datepicker in angular-ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use datepicker component from angular-ui bootstrap lib as descibed here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
And I try to set options for the popup picker and accoriding to the documentation I should pass options for datepicker as JSON using the datepicker-options attribute.

In my view I have:

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
    $scope.dateOptions = {'show-button-bar': 'false', 'close-text':'SomeText'};

    $scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.showWeeks = false;

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yy'",
        'starting-day': 1
    };
    $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

As you can see at the beginning I try to set the options:

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {'show-button-bar': 'false', 'close-text':'SomeText'};
```

however, it doesn't seem to work, the datepicker does not change.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're shadowing the first dateOptions with the second at the bottom. Have you tried combining the two asssignments into one object?

Comment: That's true, however, merging the two assignments did not help.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution to this, I put the options as attributes, e.g.:

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2014-12-31'" datepickerOptions="dateOptions" ng-required="true" show-button-bar="false"/>
```

so I put show-button-bar as the attribute and not as a part of object passed to datepickerOptions.

Comment: datepickerOptions probably should be datepicker-options, but this solution does work.

Answer (score 8):

You are using **dash-cased** option names. These dash-cased names are only required when using them as single attributes on an element. i.e.

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" starting-day="1" ng-model="dt" >
```

However `datepicker-options` expects named options in json with **camelCased** format as following:

`datepicker-options="{startingDay: 1, yearFormat: 'yy'}"`

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
       datepicker-options="{startingDay: 1, yearFormat: 'yy'}" ng-model="dt" >
```

or

```
$scope.options = {
    'startingDay': 1,
    'yearFormat': 'yy'
}

<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
       datepicker-options="{{options}}" ng-
```

The attribute `starting-day="1"` should also work on the datepicker input, as told at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker, but I can't seem to get that working (using version 0.12.1)

Comment: what is the use of having yearFormat: 'yy', in options?

Comment: @HVarma I do not know the use of the 'yy' option. It was just a (working) example. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date for available formats in angular. I used 'yy' because the default is already 'yyyy'. See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker for the defaults

Answer (score 5):

I know this an old question but thought I'd point out where you were probably having trouble.

In your controller you are assigning to `$scope.dateOptions` **twice** and therefore overwriting your first assignment.

So your initial assignment of:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {'show-button-bar': 'false', 'close-text':'SomeText'};
```

Is overwritten when you do this towards the end:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
};
```

Answer (score 5):

According to datePicker [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), popup setting can be globally configured through the datepickerPopupConfig, so you have to add it into you controller.

```
yourApp.controller('YourController', function ($scope, datepickerPopupConfig) {
  datepickerPopupConfig.showButtonBar = true;
  datepickerPopupConfig.closeText = 'I am done';
  datepickerPopupConfig.clearText = 'Wipe it out';
}
```

Setting `closeText` doesn't work for some reason. I don't know why.

Example on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdT7pikeEXUSjdS9r6jG?p=preview) for playing.

Answer (score 1):

datepicker-options was introduced in version 0.11 so make sure you are using angular-ui-bootstrap version 0.11 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `dateOptions` object keys are not **camelCased**. Try this:

```js
$scope.dateOptions = {
    'showButtonBar': 'false', 
    'closeText':'SomeText'
};
```

Html attributes should be **dash-cased**, like `show-button-bar`, or `close-text`, etc.

Notice the difference between the `datepicker-options` **html attribute** and the `datepickerOptions` **javascript object**.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide close-text, current-text and clear-text attributes in the input :)

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.isopen" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="your close text here" current-text="Your current text here (today for example)" clear-text="Your clear-text here"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The site is pretty lite on examples. For me, with version 1.1.1, I passed in the config object as an attrib:

```
datepicker-options="datepickerOptions"
```

And in the controller, was able to set some options:

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 0,
    showWeeks: false
};
```

But 'showButtonBar' doesn't cooperate, so looking through the code I saw 'uibDatepickerPopupConfig'. I pass that in and and set it separately and it works:

```
.controller('DatepickerCtrl', function ($scope, uibDatepickerPopupConfig){

    uibDatepickerPopupConfig.showButtonBar = false;
```

With 'datepickerPopupConfig' I get the provider error:

```
Unknown provider: datepickerPopupConfigProvider <- datepickerPopupConfig
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11164864)

Comment: I was just expanding on previous answers with some details more relevant to 2016, but I suppose I could have done that via a comment.